# after clicking a link, on the next page some radiobutton is checked

Tags: radio-button

I'm looking for a solution for my problem,
There are 3 links on a page, when clicking on one of the links there loads a new page. 
On that new page there are 3 checkboxes.

When clicking on link 1 of the first page the radiobutton 1 on the new page needs to be checked, link 2 -> checkbox 2, etc.

I think there are 3 options to do this, with sessionStorage, cookies or use some URL ?var. 
Seems I can't use php into the form.

How can I get this to work, don't care much how it's done.
Any help really appreciated!

#### edit this is solved

```
<input type="radio" name="amount" value="1" /> 1 <br>
<input type="radio" name="amount" value="2" /> 2 <br>
<input type="radio" name="amount" value="3" /> 3 <br>


<script>
function getQueryVariable(variable) {
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split('=');
        if (decodeURIComponent(pair[0]) == variable) {
            return decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
        }
    }
    }


var am=getQueryVariable("amount");
var allElems = document.getElementsByName('amount');
for (i = 0; i < allElems.length; i++) {
    if (allElems[i].type == 'radio' && allElems[i].value ==am ) {
        allElems[i].checked = true;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: can yu give the code behind file of your page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set each link on page 1 to go to page2.html?link={insert_number_here}.
Then check on the new page the $_GET['link'] and process further.

```
<a href="page2.html?link=1">Link 1</a>
<a href="page2.html?link=2">Link 2</a>
<a href="page2.html?link=3">Link 3</a>
```

On page 2 next to the first radio button write:

```
<input type="radio" <?php if($_GET['link']==1){echo 'checked="checked"';} ?>/>
<input type="radio" <?php if($_GET['link']==2){echo 'checked="checked"';} ?>/>
<input type="radio" <?php if($_GET['link']==3){echo 'checked="checked"';} ?>/>
```

Comment: Sorry it took so long to awnser, I need to check if it's possible in this cms if i can use php into my form chunk (modx eform). Thanks.